# Замена значений QLabel и QRadiobutton с использованием файла .json

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, qlabel, qradiobutton

Пишу программу похожую на обычную викторину.
Есть файл **data.json**, в котором записаны следующие данные:

1. Вопрос
2. Варианты ответа
3. Номер верного ответа.

Моя программа написана на *PyQt*, интерфейс присутствует. Я хочу лишь понять как мне данные из файла **data.json** использовать так, чтобы:

- Вопрос из json заменял пустое значение `label`.
- Варианты ответов вставлялись в наименования `radiobutton`.
- А верный ответ под номер `radiobutton`.

Для примера который более менее подходит предоставлю эту программу:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import json


class Quiz:
    def __init__(self):

        self.q_no = 0

        self.display_title()
        self.display_question()

        self.opt_selected = IntVar()
        self.opts = self.radio_buttons()
        self.display_options()

        self.buttons()

        self.data_size = len(question)
        self.correct = 0

    def display_result(self):
        wrong_count = self.data_size - self.correct
        correct = f"Correct: {self.correct}"
        wrong = f"Wrong: {wrong_count}"

        score = int(self.correct / self.data_size * 100)
        result = f"Score: {score}%"

        mb.showinfo("Result", f"{result}\n{correct}\n{wrong}")

    def check_ans(self, q_no):
        if self.opt_selected.get() == answer[q_no]:
            return True

    def next_btn(self):
        if self.check_ans(self.q_no):
            self.correct += 1

        self.q_no += 1

        if self.q_no == self.data_size:
            self.display_result()
            gui.destroy()
        else:
            self.display_question()
            self.display_options()

    def buttons(self):
        next_button = Button(gui, text="Next", command=self.next_btn,
                             width=10, bg="blue", fg="white", font=("ariel", 16, "bold"))

        next_button.place(x=350, y=380)
        quit_button = Button(gui, text="Quit", command=gui.destroy,
                             width=5, bg="black", fg="white", font=("ariel", 16, " bold"))

        quit_button.place(x=700, y=50)

    def display_options(self):
        val = 0
        self.opt_selected.set(0)

        for option in options[self.q_no]:
            self.opts[val]['text'] = option
            val += 1

    def display_question(self):
        q_no = Label(gui, text=question[self.q_no], width=60,
                     font=('ariel', 16, 'bold'), anchor='w')

        q_no.place(x=70, y=100)

    def display_title(self):
        # The title to be shown
        title = Label(gui, text="Тест закинуть в программу",
                      width=50, bg="green", fg="white", font=("ariel", 20, "bold"))

        title.place(x=0, y=2)

    def radio_buttons(self):
        q_list = []
        y_pos = 150

        while len(q_list) < 4:
            radio_btn = Radiobutton(gui, text=" ", variable=self.opt_selected,
                                    value=len(q_list) + 1, font=("ariel", 14))

            q_list.append(radio_btn)

            radio_btn.place(x=100, y=y_pos)

            y_pos += 40
        return q_list

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("800x450")
gui.title("Тест в программу интерфейс вопросы")

with open('data.json', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

question = (data['question'])
options = (data['options'])
answer = (data['answer'])

quiz = Quiz()

gui.mainloop()
```

---

**data.json**:

```
{
  "question": [
    "Q1. Тут вопрос?",
    "Q2. Тут вопрос?",
    "Q3. Тут вопрос?",
    "Q4. Тут вопрос?"
  ],
  "answer": [
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
  ],
  "options": [

    ["Ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ"
    ],
    ["Ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ"
    ],
    ["Ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ"
    ],
    ["Ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

Я понимаю как это работает с *Tkinter*, но не понимаю как это все реализовать в *PyQt*. 
Сам интерфейс, кнопки, поле для вопроса все есть. Нужно только подключить **data.json** и заменять значения label и radiobutton на значения из файлов после каждого вопроса.

Comment: Данила, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        with open('data.json', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        self.question = (data['question'])
        self.options = (data['options'])
        self.answer = (data['answer'])
        
        self.data_size = len(self.question)
        self.q_no = 0
        self.correct = 0
        self.setObjectName('example')
        
        self.title = QLabel("Тест закинуть в программу", 
            objectName='title', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.quit_button = QPushButton("Quit", objectName='quit_button')
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.close)
            
        self.label_q_no = QLabel(
            self.question[self.q_no], 
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter,
            objectName='label_q_no'
        )
     
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title, 0, 0, 1, 3,  alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.quit_button, 1, 2,  
            alignment=Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_q_no, 3, 0, 1, 3)

        self.radiobuttons = {}
        list_rb = [] 
        self.radiobutton_1 = QRadioButton(self.options[self.q_no][0])
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton_1, 4, 0, 1, 3)
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_1)
        self.radiobutton_2 = QRadioButton(self.options[self.q_no][1])
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton_2, 5, 0, 1, 3)
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_2)
        self.radiobutton_3 = QRadioButton(self.options[self.q_no][2])
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton_3, 6, 0, 1, 3)
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_3)        
        self.radiobutton_4 = QRadioButton(self.options[self.q_no][3])
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton_4, 7, 0, 1, 3)
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_4)        
        self.radiobuttons[self.q_no] = list_rb
        self.radiobutton_5 = QRadioButton()
        
        self._group = QButtonGroup(self)
        self._group.addButton(self.radiobutton_1, 0)
        self._group.addButton(self.radiobutton_2, 1)
        self._group.addButton(self.radiobutton_3, 2)
        self._group.addButton(self.radiobutton_4, 3)
        self._group.addButton(self.radiobutton_5, 4)
        
        self.layout.setRowStretch(8, 1)
        self.next_button = QPushButton("Next", objectName='next_button')
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next_btn) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.next_button, 9, 1,  
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

    def next_btn(self):        
        correct_answer = self.answer[self.q_no]
        rb = self.radiobuttons[self.q_no][correct_answer]
        if rb.isChecked():
            self.correct += 1
        
        self.q_no += 1
        if self.q_no >= self.data_size:
            self.next_button.setEnabled(False)
            text = f'''<br>Score&nbsp;&nbsp;: {int(self.correct / self.data_size * 100)}%<br>
Correct&nbsp;: {self.correct}&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
Wrong&nbsp;&nbsp;: {self.data_size - self.correct}&nbsp;&nbsp;'''
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Результат', 
                f"<p style='color: white; text-align: center; \
                font: 15pt \"Consolas\" Bold'>{text}</p>",
            )
            return
        
        self.label_q_no.setText(self.question[self.q_no]) 
        list_rb = []
        self.radiobutton_5.setChecked(True)
        self.radiobutton_1.setText(self.options[self.q_no][0]) 
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_1)
        self.radiobutton_2.setText(self.options[self.q_no][1]) 
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_2)
        self.radiobutton_3.setText(self.options[self.q_no][2]) 
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_3)
        self.radiobutton_4.setText(self.options[self.q_no][3]) 
        list_rb.append(self.radiobutton_4)
        self.radiobuttons[self.q_no] = list_rb
        
        
QSS = '''
#example {
    background-color: #F0E68C;
}
#title {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font: 25pt "ariel" bold;
    max-height: 50px;
}
#label_q_no {
    background-color: #F0E68C;
    color: #000080;
    font: 17pt "ariel" bold;
}
#quit_button {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font: 16pt "ariel" bold;
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 70px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
#next_button {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font: 16pt "ariel" bold;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
QRadioButton {
    background-color: #F0E68C;
    color: #000;
    font: 15pt "ariel" bold;
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
QMessageBox {
    background: black;
    messagebox-information-icon: url(./images/Close.png);
}
QMessageBox QPushButton {
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
}
QMessageBox QPushButton:hover {
    background: darkCyan;
}
QDialogButtonBox {
    dialogbuttonbox-buttons-have-icons: 1;
    dialog-ok-icon: url(./images/Ok.png);
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    w = Example()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**data.json**:

```
{
  "question": [
    "Q1. Тут вопрос 1?",
    "Q2. Тут вопрос 2?",
    "Q3. Тут вопрос 3?",
    "Q4. Тут вопрос 4?"
  ],
  "answer": [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "options": [
    ["Ответ правильный1",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ"
    ],
    ["Не ответ",
      "Ответ правильный2",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ"
    ],
    ["Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Ответ правильный3",
      "Не ответ"
    ],
    ["Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Не ответ",
      "Ответ правильный4"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ДанилаМарковский что не так?